# Change comma separated date format 20,190,927 in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame with date columns as 20,190,927 which means: 2019/09/27.
I need to change the format to YYYY/MM/DD or something similar.

I thought of doing it manually like:

```
x = df_all['CREATION_DATE'].str[:2] + df_all['CREATION_DATE'].str[3:5] + "-" + \
    df_all['CREATION_DATE'].str[5] + df_all['CREATION_DATE'].str[7] + "-" + df_all['CREATION_DATE'].str[8:]

print(x)
```

What's a more creative way of doing this? Could it be done with datetime module?

Comment: Why would you want a more creative way? What's is it that you dislike about your solution? Assuming the commas you have put in are just for display (rather confusing as it's not a number, just a sequence of digits) then you could read it in using the strptime function in datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. First replace the `,` with nothing, so you get a yyyymmdd format, and then change it to `datetime` with `pd.to_datetime` by passing the correct format. One liner:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str.replace(',',''),format='%Y%m%d')
```

Full explanation:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'dates':['20,190,927','20,191,114'],'values':[1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

Output, here's how the original dataframe looks like:

```
        dates  values
0  20,190,927       1
1  20,191,114       2

df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(',','')
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'],format='%Y%m%d')
print(df)
print(df.info())
```

Output of the newly formatted dataframe:

```
       dates  values
0 2019-09-27       1
1 2019-11-14       2
```

Printing `.info()` to ensure we have the correct format:

```
dates     2 non-null datetime64[ns]
values    2 non-null int64
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a much better way than what I had.

Comment: I am glad to help, you can use the one liner to make less lines of code. If the answer was helpful make sure to accept it so you give help others with the same issue find the solution quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
date=['20,190,927','20,190,928','20,190,929']
df3=pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['Date'])
df3['Date']=df3['Date'].replace('\,','',regex=True)
df3['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df3['Date'])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Josue Barrantes Can you accept the this as an answer, by clicking the onto the tick below